# Code exits method permanently when modifying class variable

Tags: c#

I just started a new windows form project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I have a csv file that I made and can verify through messagebox alerts that it's being read correctly, however when I try to construct an array that was declared in the parent class, it seems the code exits the method permanently.

Current code (reduced to just relevant pieces)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    FileStream fs;
    StreamReader sr;
    public string[][] myTable;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog filediag = new OpenFileDialog();
        filediag.Filter = "CSV files (.csv)|*.csv";
        filediag.Multiselect = false;
        filediag.ShowDialog();
        if (filediag.FileName != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("opening file"); //trying to find error point
            fs = new FileStream(filediag.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            MessageBox.Show("File open. Setting up stream reader"); //trying to find error point
            sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            MessageBox.Show("stream reader setup. begining while loop"); //trying to find error point
            int i = 0;
            string line1;
            string[] line = new string[5]; //line and line1 separate due to trying to locate issue.
           // This next line is where I have issues. 
           //A debugging breakpoint will show this line happens, however, the line after is never will. 
           //Without this line, and the myTable line within the loop, 
           //the messagebox will show for every line of the csv file indicating the while loop itself also works.
            myTable = new string[File.ReadAllLines(filediag.FileName).Count()][];
            while ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()/*.Split(',')*/) != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("in loop. line: " + line1); //trying to find error point
                i++;
                line = line1.Split(',');
                MessageBox.Show("line split and prepared for array"); //trying to find error point
                //If the previous myTable initializer doesn't exist, 
                //this will become the last line of the program on the first pass through the loop.
                myTable[i] = line;
                MessageBox.Show("line added to array. i = " + i); //trying to find error point
            }
            MessageBox.Show("final line:" + line1);
            catLabel.Show();
            catLabel.Text = myTable[0][0];
        }

    }
}
```

The Windows form will pop up right after those issue lines run, and no error shows at any point on the program. I cannot figure out what's causing it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have already opened the file with

```
fs = new FileStream(filediag.FileName, FileMode.Open);
```

And then trying to open it once again with `File.ReadAllLines(filediag.FileName)`. Maybe easier solution would be to just use `File.ReadAllLines`? For example (and with a help of generic list):

```
var content = File.ReadAllLines(filediag.FileName);
var myTable = new List<string[]>();

foreach (var line in content)
{
    myTable.Add(line.Split(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the "initializer", `myTable` is `null` which is why the program exits.

Note that this is a pretty horrible way of processing a file - for a start, you're reading the file twice (once using the `StreamReader`, then again when you do `File.ReadAllLines`). You could simplify your program a bit if you used a `List` instead of a two dimensional array. You should also put your disposables into `using` statements.

I've cut the code down a bit to the essentials:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Change to a list instead of a two-dimensional array
    public IList<string[]> myTable = new List<string[]>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog filediag = new OpenFileDialog();
        filediag.Filter = "CSV files (.csv)|*.csv";
        filediag.Multiselect = false;
        filediag.ShowDialog();

        if (filediag.FileName != null)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filediag.FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string line1;

                    // myTable has been initialised so no need for initializer here.

                    while ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()/*.Split(',')*/) != null)
                    {
                        var line = line1.Split(',');
                        myTable.Add(line);
                    }

                    catLabel.Show();
                    catLabel.Text = myTable[0][0];
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely solved the problem I was having. I'm going to have to write more stuff so I remember lists still exist the next time I have an actual project. :D. The using tip was very nice also, so thank you for that as well.